# How to get the last record value of a particular column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
select total_amount from sales_return;
```

Output:

```
total_amount
157.00
8.00
1.00
52.00
```

I'm trying to get the last value ie, `52.0`. So I tried the below query.

```
select total_amount from sales_return order by total_amount desc limit 1;
```

which shows the first value `157.00` as output. What I did wrong?

query for creating  `sales_return` table.

```
'sales_return', 'CREATE TABLE `sales_return` (
  `sales_return_no` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_return_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_no` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doctor_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_mode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_no` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_holders_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_expiry` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mfr_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `formulation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_no` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_price` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mrp` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_discount` double(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_vat` double(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_total` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_discount` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_vat` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_amount` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid_amount` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance_amount` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_items` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adj_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: 'last value' is meaningless without some field to order it on. do you have a date field or a primary key id field on each row?

Comment: don't know what you mean by data field.

Comment: `SELECT total_amount 
FROM sales_return 
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM sales_return)` If u have a column as ID or any primary key use this , just replace ur primary key on it...

Comment: it shows `unknow column id in where clause`

Comment: What are all the other columns in your sales_return table?. If you have any primary key then we can get it easily.

Comment: i'm on MySQL query browser and I don't know how to copy the entire table. There are almost 20 cols in the `sales_return` table.

Comment: Try this query. `SHOW CREATE TABLE sales_return` to see the list of columns in your table.

Comment: @user197324 i said if u have any id or primary key column use that and replace it BY 
`SELECT total_amount FROM sales_return WHERE YourcolumnPrimary= (SELECT MIN(YOURCOLUMNprimay) FROM sales_return)`

Comment: why would you even do that? it would just be `order by id dec limit 1`, but as it stands, this question is impossible to answer without the rest of the table definition

Comment: @pala_ added any further details you want?

Comment: @NaveenN I think there isn't a primary key on the `sales_return` table.

Comment: that `sales_return_date` looks like the necessary field

Comment: I would recommend you to set a column as `primary key` to get the last `total_amount`

Comment: even that is insufficient. it's perfectly possible to have a primary key that is useless for ordering

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has no concept of 'first record' or 'last record' without some context in the form of an `order by`. Without that `order by` the first and last records are indeterminate / meaningless.

From your provided table schema it would seem that `sales_return_date` would be a suitable field for determining an 'order' to the records. Ie, the last record entered, is the one entered most recently. So we need to `order by` that field, and then `limit` out results to just one 1.

```
select total_amount
  from sales_return
  order by sales_return_date desc
  limit 1
```

Comment: what if the last two dates are same?

Comment: @user197324 oh dear. its a `date` not a `datetime`. are you free to alter your table structure at all? if not, what sort of data is contained in `sales_return_no`  ? is it numeric?

Comment: @user197324 do you have any more feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

**Query:**

```
select `total_amount` from `sales_return` order by `bill_date` desc limit 1
```

The above query may give you the last `total_amount` value.

Comment: i would assume that a return happens after a sale / billing date, so the billing date would have no real bearing on the return date

Comment: Since it is your assumption, how it can be true? I say it may be. Also all columns can have null values. So it is uncertain that `sales_return_date` is the best column to choose value

Comment: because by definition you can't return something you haven't already purchased.

Comment: then the return date is after the purchase (bill) date. the order of billing date has no correlation to the order of return dates

Comment: @pala_ There is not column with `NOT NULL`, so there is no strict definition in this table. So you can't argue that `sales_return_date` is the best one to choose. I can see that the table can have null values for `sales_return_date`. I hope you are also seeing that

Comment: i'm not arguing that. i'm arguing that you can't use bill_date because its irrelevant. regardless. hence my question asking the OP if he can alter his table

Comment: @pala_ it is better to ask the questionnaire to alter his/her table structure before we discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : here adj_id is unsigned so no negative values and may be role like primary key , so try this

```
 select total_amount
      from sales_return
      order by adj_id desc
      limit 1
```

Comment: hard to make this assumption - sales_return_no is a `varchar` field, so it could very well be alphabetical for all we know